# Calling nested function from nested setInterval in an Object Namespace environment

Tags: javascript

I have this following piece of code:

```
var stats = {
....,
checkExistance :
function(url){
    var newUrl = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("/")) + "/asyncCheckChartExistance";
    var xhrObj = stats.getXhr();

    var poolInterval = setInterval("poll()", 100);

    function poll(){
        xhrObj.open("GET", newUrl, true);
        xhrObj.send(null);

        xhrObj.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xhrObj.readyState === 4 && xhrObj.status === 200){
                if (xhrObj.responseText.length === true){
                    console.log("Exists!");
                    clearInterval(poolInterval);
                } else {
                    console.log("Not Yet!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
}
```

I created the stats namespace. In this namespace I'm trying to create a function which polls the server every second. I should access this function this way: `stats.checkExistance(myUrl)`.

However it seems that the setInterval function is not able to see the `poll()` function. I know that this is normal behavior taking in consideration that these are nested inside another function.

If I were to write this in the Global namespace there would be no problem but I'm interested to make this work in this kind of namespace. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you pass a string to `setInterval`, it runs in the global scope, by default, where `poll` would not be defined since it only exists in the scope of the `checkExistance` function.

To fix the issue, pass an anonymous function to `setInterval` instead:

```
var poolInterval = setInterval(function () {
    poll();
}, 100);
```

Passing an anonymous function is usually the best idea as it allows you to write any javascript expressions/statements for the interval instead of just calling one function.

Comment: Just `setInterval( poll, 100 );` works fine. No need to wrap here. Your pattern is useful in cases where we'd want to pass one or more arguments to the target function, but that is not the case here.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas true, but if you ever need to do something more than call one function, or if you need to pass that function some parameters, an anonymous function is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a string to `setInterval`, that string is interpreted as global code, and since `poll` is not a global function, a reference error is thrown.

However, you can pass a function reference instead of a string, and since the `poll` function is available in the scope in which the `setInterval` invocation is made, you can just write this:

```
var poolInterval = setInterval( poll, 100 );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var stat = {
    say: function(name){
        function doit(){
            console.log(name);
        }
        setInterval(doit, 1000);
    }
};
stat.say("hi");​​​​​​​​​​​
```

A simple demo to show how. You will see "hi" every second.